# How to proceed to .php after fill up all textbox. My header(Location:) can`t do the thing. how can i fix this, i don`t know how

Tags: php, wordpress

Here are my codes.

```
 if(isset($_POST["Submit"])){

     $sqladd = "Insert Into `acc_temp`(Fname, Lname, Contact, 
     Email)Values('".$Fname."', '".$Lname."', '".$Number."', '".$Email."');";
     $sqladd1 = "Insert Into `anwer_temp`(User, Score)Values('".$Email."', 
     '0')";
     if($con->query($sqladd) === true){
     if($con->query($sqladd1) === true){
     session_destroy();
     session_start();
     $_SESSION["Name"] = $Email;
     header("Location:https://stlouisreviewcenter.com/wpcontent/themes/slrc/
     SLRCQuiz/Selection.php");
     }else{$con-error;}
     }else{
     echo "Please Fill up Credentials!";

     echo "error".$con->error;
     }
 }
 ?>
```

I think header() is the problem,

```
header("Location:https://stlouisreviewcenter.com/wpcontent/themes/slrc/SLRCQuiz/Selection.php");
```

instead of directing to Selection.php, it keeps going to Home page.

Comment: Judging by the overall quality of the code, I suggest you check your server logs for any error messages. I see some things that can be typo's, bugs or even syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks @BartFriederichs for response. But to be honest i dont how to do that. I`m totally new in wordpress :(

Comment: In that case, I'd advise you to do some introductory courses in PHP and SQL first.

Comment: Hahaha. i already take that course. but for me its always hard to understand some of error i encountered, so i ask here :D. i need an exact solution here

Comment: Take it again, or another one. You are making serious mistakes in your PHP and SQL code. Debugging and finding out why something does not work is also an important skill. Besides, you don't give an error, only "it doesn't work". The code on itself could work though, so it is hard for us to help you.

Comment: Never mind your form, pasting that url into the browser takes you toi the home page too. Check for a redirect in selection.php. But the other point is, it looks like the site uses pretty URL's. Have you set a route for this page? Possibly if the site uses an MVC pattern it will go through index.php, find a route, and call a controller